# How to prove that given an equality that a string is its reverse, its tail is also its reverse?

Tags: coq

```
Theorem rev_cons :
  forall X x (l : list X),
  x :: l = rev (x :: l) -> l = rev l.
```

This is just so intuitive to me that it blows my mind that I can't make any headway on it. I start off with an induction on `l`, solve the base case using reflexivity and immediately get stuck on the other.

What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's true. Case in point:

```
Require Import List.

Axiom rev_cons :
  forall X x (l : list X),
  x :: l = rev (x :: l) -> l = rev l.

Theorem argh : False.
assert (H := rev_cons _ 1 (2 :: 1 :: nil) eq_refl).
inversion H.
Qed.
```

Comment: What about in the opposite direction?

Comment: Yeah, it is not true either. I have much to learn it seems. I should have tried this on my own. I'll definitely remember to going forward.